# The value from excel file 3350032000 is read as 3.350032E9 using Java POI to read excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have used dataformatter,

```
'''cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                             
providerTitleId = cell.getStringCellValue();'''
```

and also formula evaluator, Nothing seems to work using

```
'''<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-beta5</version>
        </dependency>'''
```

can anyone kindly help in understanding whats the issue here

Comment: Is `providerTitleId` really supposed to be a `String`, not e.g. a `long`?

Comment: even if i change it to long or double the problem persists. Thank you

Comment: Can't be, because if you expect a `long` value, you would be doing `providerTitleId = (long) cell.getNumericCellValue();`, and that simply *cannot* result in the value you have.